# Web page cannot load javascript files from primefaces library

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I use primefaces 6.0 and Spark-layout in my project.
It works on localhost very well. 
But when I upload it to the server (jboss or tomcat does not differ), sometimes the page cannot load.
It happens randomly. The page stucks while loading.

When I look  the server logs :

It waits too much to log this line:
***"GET /XXX/javax.faces.resource/images/preloader.gif.xhtml?ln=spark-layout HTTP/1.1" 200 17824***

Also I have seen this in log :

***"WARNING [http-nio-80-exec-27] com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.logMissingResource JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, components.js, from library, primefaces."***

I have continued to investigate, and seen that, when the problem occurs, the page waits to load .js files from primefaces library.
Page stucks at this line in the head :

***script type="text/javascript" src="/XXX/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.0">***

Other .js files cannot be loaded:

---

> script type="text/javascript"
>   src="/XXX/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.0">
>
> script type="text/javascript"
>   src="/XXX/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.0">

---

As a result, what can I do to get rid of this problem :)
Thanks...

Comment: _"
As a result, what can I do to get rid of this problem :)"_ Configure your virusscan correctly?

Comment: tested again, and problem occured in case of active antivirus :(